# CollectionViewCell can't be display

Tags: ios

When collectionView's height is below 50, the `collectionViewCell` can't be displayed. In fact, the protocol methods

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

wouldn't be invoked.

Comment: Possibly. If the section inset is 50 or over then it wouldn't run this. Well, if the cells frame is not inside the frame of the collection view then this won't be called at all. Without any more code it's pretty much impossible to diagnose why this is happening.

Comment: What you said is a great inspiration to me. Thank you.